# Update quantity session array

Tags: php, arrays, session

I need a help

This is my **session** array:

```
Array
(
    [menu] => 
    [id] => 3
    [products] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Produkt 1
                    [code] => 1
                    [varianta] => 
                    [pocet] => 1
                    [price] => 20
                    [pricepredtym] => 40
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => Produkt 1
                    [code] => 1
                    [varianta] => 
                    [pocet] => 1
                    [price] => 20
                    [pricepredtym] => 40
                )

        )

)
```

I would need about something like, if ($_GET [id] == $ _SESSION ['products'] [id]) and only change this "[pocet]" where [id] = 2

**$_GET [id] = 2;**
 **$pocet=5;**

```
[1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => Produkt 1
                    [code] => 1
                    [varianta] => 
                    [pocet] => 5
                    [price] => 20
                    [pricepredtym] => 40
                )
```

Comment: can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Where does the `$pocet` value come from? Is it from `$_GET` too?

Comment: Môžeš meniť ten session array alebo musí ostať ako je? V prvom prípade by si mohol id produktu použiť ako kľúč v poli products a pristupovať priamo k tomuto produktu cez $sessionArray['products'][$_GET['id']]. V druhom prípade musíš foreachovat pole products a porovnávať id s tým co je v gete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could index your `products` array by product id. Then updating would be simply:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['products'][$prod_id])) {
    $_SESSION['products'][$prod_id]['pocet'] = $pocet;
}
```

Otherwise, use a foreach loop:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['products'] as $i => $prod) {
    if ($prod['id'] == $prod_id) {
        $_SESSION['products'][$i]['pocet'] = $pocet;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare your `GET` value with `2` and use it as key of `SESSION` array.

```
if ($_GET['id'] == '2'){
    $_SESSION['products'][$_GET['id']]['pocet'] = '5';
}
```

Comment: Array
(
    [menu] => 
    [id] => 1
    [products] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Produkt 1
                    [code] => 1
                    [varianta] => 
                    [pocet] => 1
                    [price] => 20
                    [pricepredtym] => 40
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [pocet] => 5
                )

        )

)